# Installation of permanent stairway into the loft

Tags: wood, support

Want to replace a loft ladder with a permanent stairway. The new stairway has to be over the existing stairway because of restricted space. The only load bearing wall is a gable wall. What I want to do is attach the new stairways quarter landing to the gable wall in order to avoid having to have support legs. The new stairway would be made from redwood pine and the landing would be approx 650 mm square. Is this possible and if so how would it be done.

Comment: You need to show the relationship between the existing stair and the purposed modification. Are you thinking to add a short stair with a landing that is 90 degree turns from the upper segment? Your description is confusing.

Comment: Do you live in a place with zoning or building regulations?   I ask, because this question is probably one for an architect, and in most places adding  a staircase and creating new living space on a new floor would require permits that in turn require the involvement of an architect and/or engineer.  I  believe any advice you get here may be of limited value.

Comment: This needs _so_ much more detail before anyone would even have a _chance_ of answering. A floor plan would be an ideal start, but even a sketch with dimensions drawn in would help. I will 2nd the notion that permits might be necessary (depending on what the attic will be used for), and at a minimum, someone on-site would be better placed to analyze what kind of structural support there would be for a new staircase.